# how to know who has subscribed to my RSS?

Tags: php, rss

is there any PHP script or other software that could let me know who has subscribed to my RSS feeds? (**server part or personal-browser/RSS-reader**)

My RSS files are all generated by a PHP script, then I use an `.htaccess` URL rewrite rule in order to make the file accessible as `.xml`.

I know some methods like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but I have no confidence to write some reliable code by myself. So, I am looking for some stable code which could help me know who has subscribed to my RSS feeds (and store it into MySQL)?

Answer (score 2):

**Two options for tracking RSS feed subscriptions**

*–a simple, non-technical explanation of your options*

Website log files

If you have access to your website’s log files and know what you are looking for, you could go through it to see how many times your RSS feed was requested.  A request for my RSS feed by my computer looked like this:

65.13.85.140 – - [18/Feb/2010:04:40:28 -0500] “GET /?feed=rss2 HTTP/1.1″ 304 159 “-” “Apple-PubSub/65.11″

This could be quite time consuming.  I have a new log file generated each day; however, that is a configuration I set up.  The default configuration for my website host was one log file.  That could be quite cumbersome to count, and if your site gets a lot of traffic almost impossible.  You web server may have some basic statistics that will log an xml request.  If your site has a static page for it’s RSS, you may be able to locate how many times it is requested by finding its filename.  This will not work, however, if you are using a statistic service like Google Analytics because you cannot put Javascript code in your RSS feed’s xml file.

*Use transparent png “bugs”*

You can use a uniquely named transparent 1×1 png file and add it to the description field of an RSS feed. Then using your website logs (see option one) see the number of times the image is viewed and determine the number of times the feed was accessed.  Again, like option number one, not very effective for basically all the same reasons.  Furthermore, depending on your how your RSS feed is generated and how you implement the the png bug; it could totally give you the wrong stats and impressions:  you may think your feed is a hit when actually the counts are for every view of your post–just depends.

Comment: Website log files? i'd rather to use php `$_SERVER` to get visitors info (ip,browser,os...). Google Analytics, that might be a good way, but i need return data to my database for some process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Big RSS aggregators like e.g. Feedly, Pulse etc. probably fetch your feed for performance reasons only once and display it to several users. So one hit measured by the web server logs may count for a lot of users - but you don't know if it's only one user of Feedly or 100.

Same for png webbugs: If Feedly fetches the feed once and displays it multiple times, every user sees the same png image. So you can't say if 100 users saw the image once or one user saw the image 100 times (second option is unlikely, but the truth will lie somewhere in between). If the image will be cached by a proxy (Gmail does this for images embedded in Mails) you'll only have one request at all.

I don't know how services like Feedburner get their numbers, but i think they only estimate.

*Addition*: [Here's Feedburner's way](https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/78955) of calculating the subscribers (**bold text** by me to emphasize the uncertainty):

> ## How is it calculated?
>
> FeedBurner’s subscriber count is based on an **approximation** of how many
> times your feed has been requested in a 24-hour period. Subscribers is
> **inferred from an analysis of the many different feed readers** and
> aggregators that retrieve this feed daily. Subscribers is not computed
> for browsers and bots that access your feed.
>
> Subscribers counts are calculated by matching IP address and feed
> reader combinations, then **using our detailed understanding of the
> multitude of readers, aggregators, and bots on the market** to make
> additional inferences.

Answer (score 0):

*A more technical answer that may be what you're looking for*

To read a RSS feed, it has to be requested. This means that all of the request data (remote IP, user agent, etc) gets sent in a HTTP request. You can use the relevant `$_SERVER` variables (or however else you want to get the data) to record the data, and then send it to your database or wherever.

[user3237855](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3237855/user3237855) mentioned Google Analytics, which has a REST API you could send data to in order to help consolidate data. You wouldn't get nearly as much intel as Analytic's JavaScript bug, but you can't really get that in any way with a RSS feed.
Or, of course, just keep the data in your database for whatever your uses.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you can implement the use of `cookies` in your `PHP generated RSS feed`. Every time your RSS feed is `requested` by a client, you could determine whether a `cookie exists`.

```
if($_COOKIE['knownVisitor']){
    // store as subscriber
}else{
    setcookie("knownVisitor", true);
}
```

I tried to find whether this works on every client. But i am not sure. But this way you could identify whether a user has contacted your feed before. You could even give the Cookie the current `timeStamp` as value, so you could compare the time between multiple requests (10 times in 5 seconds does not make you a subscriber, it makes you a person who has to get their `f5 key` unstuck).

Comment: I realise that. We have those laws in Holland as well. You can do this if it is of neccesaty for your users browsing experience. You can do it without consent in that case. Anyhow, this is the way to do what you want, and the cookie law is something that is very vague. Basically if you add a message on your site, saying the RSS uses cookies, the users are supposed to know they download cookies when using the RSS. That way you follow the law close enough. I did my research.!

Answer (score 0):

```
...
$zrecord->setAttribute('userAgent',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
...

I use this, to make some statistics - who is browser agent etc etc

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR    
2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; da; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 
3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)

ans so on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call Google Analytics from php. This gives you much more information than you would get by trying to write your own tracking logic. https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Comment: @fishman That's what I sent you. This is a port of Google's javascript api to php. An rss feed cannot embed javascript code in the generated page. So the tracking has to be done from Php. I've provided exactly what you requested.

Comment: So any php script can do that? `piwik` or `owa`? Google Analytics api has day limit, It is impossible update my mysql table in real time.

Comment: Sure. If nothing else, the source for their script will help you roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Some opinion, You can store ip into database, then analyse each ip address (the frequency visit your site, if it is a auto script, the visit time will obey some rule, like: 0:00, 1:00, 2:00 ...)

Another way, put ip into "http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A".$ip, if it is from some site server, bing will list the domain of this ip. (But still a problem, if some small site from web hosting, many sites will share in one ip address).